# how to sum up the total value?

Tags: java

```
for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {

        try {
            System.out
                    .println(" _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  ");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("The word inputted : " + word2);
            File file = new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc" + a
                            + ".txt");
            System.out.println(" _________________");

            System.out.print("| File = abc" + a + ".txt | \t\t \n");

            for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {

                totalCount = 0;
                wordCount = 0;

                Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
                {
                    while (s.hasNext()) {
                        totalCount++;
                        if (s.next().equals(array2[i]))
                            wordCount++;

                    }

                    System.out.print(array2[i] + " --> Word count =  "
                            + "\t " + "|" + wordCount + "|");
                    System.out.print("  Total count = " + "\t " + "|"
                            + totalCount + "|");
                    System.out.printf("  Term Frequency =  | %8.4f |",
                            (double) wordCount / totalCount);

                    System.out.println("\t ");

                    double inverseTF =  Math.log10((float) numDoc
                            / (numofDoc[i]));
                    System.out.println("    --> IDF = " + inverseTF );

                    double TFIDF = (((double) wordCount / totalCount) * inverseTF);
                    System.out.println("    --> TF/IDF = " + TFIDF + "\n");



                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File is not found");
        }
    }
}
```

}

this is the example output :

The word inputted : how are you

---

| File = abc0.txt |

how --> Word count =     |4|  Total count =      |957|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0042 |

```
--> IDF = 0.5642714398516419

--> TF/IDF = 0.0023585013159943234
```

are --> Word count =     |7|  Total count =      |957|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0073 |

```
--> IDF = 0.1962946357308887

--> TF/IDF = 0.00143580193324579
```

you --> Word count =     |10|  Total count =     |957|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0104 |

```
--> IDF = 0.1962946357308887

--> TF/IDF = 0.002051145618922557
```

How do i sum up the entire 3 TF/IDF for each text file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asssuming you just want a running total to be able to display, then prior to your `for loop` add something like:

```
double runningTfIDF = 0;
```

Then immediately after calculating the current TF/IDF, then add the line

```
runningTfIDF += TFIDF;
```

Then, after your `for loop`, you can add a line to print the runningTfIDF.

**edited to included more complete answer**

```
HashMap<String, BigDecimal> runningTdIDF = new HashMap<String, Double>();
HashMap<String, BigDecimal> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Double>();
HashMap<String, BigDecimal> frequency = new HashMap<String, Double>();
HashMap<String, BigDecimal> inverseTF = new HashMap<String, Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {

    totalCount = 0;
    wordCountVal = 0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    {
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            totalCount++;
            if (s.next().equals(array2[i]))
                 wordCountVal++;

            }

            BigDecimal wordCount(array2[i],new BigDecimal(wordCountVal));

            BigDecimal frequencyVal = new BigDecimal( (double) wordCount / totalCount));
        frequency.put(array2[i],frequencyVal);

            BigDecimal inverseTFVal =  new BigDecimal(Math.log10((float) numDoc
                            / (numofDoc[i])));
        inverseTF.put(array2[i], inverseTFVal);


            BigDecaim TFIDF =new BigDecima( (( wordCount / totalCount) * inverseTF));
            runningTfIDF.put(array2[i], TFIDF);

    }

    for(String word : wordCount.keySet()){
         System.out.print(word + " --> word count " 
        + "\t |"+wordCount.get(word)+"|");
         System.out.print("  Total count = " + "\t " + "|"
             + totalCount + "|");
         System.out.printf("  Term Frequency =  | %8.4f |",
             frequency.get(word));

         System.out.println("\t ");

         System.out.println("    --> IDF = " + inverseTF.get(word));

         System.out.println("    --> TF/IDF = " + runningTfIDF.get(word) + "\n");
    }
```

}

That isn't the cleanest possible implementation by far, but in short you need to store your information for each word and cycle through the words after you've created your totals if you want to display the total starting with the first possible result.  Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks sir, but i need to total it and display it under TF/IDF of each of the word.. Can sir guide me ?

Comment: Do you mean that you would display TFIDF for the first word twice, the TFIDF for the 2nd, followed by the sum TFIDF?  You could print the runningTfIDF at each iteration and it would give you the sum at that point in time.

Comment: i mean giving the entire [3 word total sum] by the first word..sorry for make it so confusing..

Comment: Ahh.  In that case you'd want to set things up differently.  I'll edit my answer.